# Incomplete displaying JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel, when I run it it displays only half of it, it doesn't display full window.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Elham
 */
public class signUpForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form signUpForm
     */
    public signUpForm() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanelHeader = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabelClose = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelMin = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelCreateNewAccount = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanelBody = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabelFirstName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelPass = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextFieldUserName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordFieldPass = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButtonCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonCreate = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabelLogin = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelUserName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelRetypePass = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPasswordFieldPass1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabelPhoto = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelPic = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButtonBrowse = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextFieldFirstName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextFieldLastName = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(460, 447));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jPanelHeader.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(46, 204, 113));
        jPanelHeader.setLayout(null);

        jLabelClose.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabelClose.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelClose.setText("x");
        jLabelClose.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jLabelClose.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabelCloseMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanelHeader.add(jLabelClose);
        jLabelClose.setBounds(410, 20, 15, 29);

        jLabelMin.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabelMin.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelMin.setText("-");
        jLabelMin.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jLabelMin.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabelMinMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanelHeader.add(jLabelMin);
        jLabelMin.setBounds(390, 20, 10, 29);

        jLabelCreateNewAccount.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabelCreateNewAccount.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelCreateNewAccount.setText("Create new account");
        jPanelHeader.add(jLabelCreateNewAccount);
        jLabelCreateNewAccount.setBounds(25, 23, 250, 29);

        getContentPane().add(jPanelHeader);
        jPanelHeader.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 70);

        jPanelBody.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(44, 62, 80));

        jLabelFirstName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelFirstName.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelFirstName.setText("First Name:");

        jLabelPass.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelPass.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelPass.setText("Password:");

        jTextFieldUserName.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(108, 122, 137));
        jTextFieldUserName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextFieldUserName.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 204));
        jTextFieldUserName.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextFieldUserNameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPasswordFieldPass.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(108, 122, 137));
        jPasswordFieldPass.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jPasswordFieldPass.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 204));
        jPasswordFieldPass.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jPasswordFieldPassActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButtonCancel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 38, 19));
        jButtonCancel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButtonCancel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButtonCancel.setText("Cancel");

        jButtonCreate.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 139, 195));
        jButtonCreate.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButtonCreate.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButtonCreate.setText("Create");

        jLabelLogin.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
        jLabelLogin.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelLogin.setText("Already have an accoutn? Click here to login");
        jLabelLogin.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jLabelLogin.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabelLoginMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabelUserName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelUserName.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelUserName.setText("Username:");

        jLabelRetypePass.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelRetypePass.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelRetypePass.setText("Retype Pass:");

        jPasswordFieldPass1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(108, 122, 137));
        jPasswordFieldPass1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jPasswordFieldPass1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 204));

        jLabelPhoto.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabelPhoto.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabelPhoto.setText("Photo");

        jLabelPic.setText("jLabel1");

        jButtonBrowse.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButtonBrowse.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButtonBrowse.setText("Browse");

        jTextFieldFirstName.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(108, 122, 137));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Last Name:");

        jTextFieldLastName.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(108, 122, 137));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanelBodyLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanelBody);
        jPanelBody.setLayout(jPanelBodyLayout);
        jPanelBodyLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabelFirstName)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldFirstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldLastName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabelUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(jTextFieldUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabelPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jPasswordFieldPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabelRetypePass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jPasswordFieldPass1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabelPhoto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabelPic, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 177, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                .addComponent(jButtonBrowse))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                .addComponent(jButtonCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jButtonCreate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 121, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                .addComponent(jLabelLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 260, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        jPanelBodyLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelFirstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldFirstName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldLastName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordFieldPass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelRetypePass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordFieldPass1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                        .addComponent(jLabelPhoto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jLabelPic, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButtonBrowse, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(jPanelBodyLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButtonCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButtonCreate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jLabelLogin))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanelBody);
        jPanelBody.setBounds(0, 70, 450, 480);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jLabelCloseMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jLabelMinMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }                                      

    private void jTextFieldUserNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                  

    private void jLabelLoginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        loginForm logf = new loginForm();
        logf.setVisible(true);
        logf.pack();
        logf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        logf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jPasswordFieldPassActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(signUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(signUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(signUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(signUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new signUpForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonBrowse;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCreate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelClose;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelCreateNewAccount;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelFirstName;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelLogin;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelMin;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelPass;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelPhoto;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelPic;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelRetypePass;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelUserName;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelBody;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanelHeader;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordFieldPass;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordFieldPass1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldFirstName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldLastName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldUserName;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is what the code produces:
[image]
How can I make the code display the full JPanel?

Comment: I recommend you to stop using the IDE's GUI Builder and write the code on your own. IDE inserts too much useless code and makes the code harder to read. If you write the code for the same GUI should take you ~50 - 80 lines of code. Currently there's not more help that we could provide given that all the code is written by your IDE.

Comment: `setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(460, 447));` and `getContentPane().setLayout(null);` are going to screw with you

Comment: Using a GUI Build is a good, practical idea.  However the code it produces is hard to read.  As MadProgrammer says, `setLayout(null)` is NOT what a GUI Builder expects.  It needs layout managers to do its job.  Don't set the layout to null, use a layout manager.

Comment: It's not a bad question, but the fact that the code is auto-generated makes it *so* hard to read :( P.S.: Remember to capitalize class names

Comment: For auto-generated code like this it's important to remove any code that isn't directly related to the problem.  Seeing repeated initialization of First Name, Last Name, User Name, etc. when those parts are working isn't helping.  A *minimal* example would omit the obviously working parts.

Comment: I think @MadProgrammer hit the nail on the head. Here are some general tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: So, you need something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ6nI.png)?

Comment: Yes my project is same like but when I run it, it doesn't display the bottom of it where the buttons are located. @AndrewThompson

Comment: I guess the problem is that I've set layouts of every container(JFrames and JPanels) to null :(

Comment: *"I guess the problem is that I've set layouts of every container(JFrames and JPanels) to null"* That's a pretty safe guess. So the question now is, how are you going to proceed?